# jquery ui dialog - fade-in after effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-effects

```
function infoBox(title,text){
    $('.infobox').dialog({
    open: function( event, ui ) {$('.infobox').append('<p style="display:none;>'+text+'</p>'); 
    },
    beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {$('.infobox p').remove(); 
    },
    show:'drop' ,
    position:'top',
    title:title,
});
};
```

**is out there something like an `afteropen:` option ?**

or any other way to let the appended text fade in after the ui-effect has finished?

maybe something like something like: `show:[{show:'drop', function(){$('.infobox p').fadeIn();}],`

**?** thanks in advance

Comment: show:'drop' initiates the effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for.  Just use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).

```
function infoBox(title,text){
        $('.infobox').dialog({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            var p = $('<p style="display:none;">'+text+'</p>')
            $('.infobox').append(p);
            p.delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
        },
        beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {$('.infobox p').remove(); 
        },
        show:'drop' ,
        position:'top',
        title:title,
    });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yTMwu/69/

---

EDIT:
You can also write it like this:

```
$('.infobox').append('<p style="display:none;">'+text+'</p>').find('p').delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yTMwu/70/

Comment: maybe you could correct me, do i have to to set variable p with $() and the string inside to make them a jquery-object and only then i can apply the effects? i dont understand that ..but it looks awesome with my css =]

Comment: Exactly, otherwise it won't allow you to use `.delay()`.  However, if you are not a fan of that, I have added another way of writing it in my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5R49y/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="infobox" title="dialog"></div>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery / jQuery UI):**

```
function infoBox(title, text) {
    $('.infobox').dialog({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var p = $('<p/>').append(text).hide().fadeIn(2000)
            $('.infobox').append(p);

 },
        beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
            $('.infobox p').remove();
        },
        show: 'drop',
        position: 'top',
        title: title
    });
}

$(function(){
    infoBox('Title','Lorem ipsum');
});
```

Comment: thx, but a delay is mor suitable for me as the element would fade in very slow, my ui-dialog css has height open and may its a nice effect to let the box float in only with title bar and then "build" the text

Comment: Just add a `delay()` to the chain, just before the `fadeIn()`